# Ngfor get the name from one array where the id = the id from another array and add a comma till the last element

Tags: angular, string, formatting, ngfor, angular-ng-if

```
export class Task implements ITask {
  id:number;
  name:string;
  employees:number[];
}

export class Employee implements IEmployee {
  id: number;
  department_id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  birth_date: string;
}

apiEmployees:Employee[];
apiTasks:Task[];
//task of apiTasks
```

I would like to display the employee names of the employees for a certain task. I managed to do it like this but the problem is that it does not remove the last comma and i do not know how to fix that problem:

```
<span *ngFor="let employee of apiEmployees let isLastTaskEmployee=last">
            <span *ngIf="task.employees.includes(employee.id) ">
              {{employee.first_name}}
              {{employee.last_name}}
              {{isLastTaskEmployee
                ?'' : ', '}}
            </span>
          </span>
```

I would like a different approach because this creates a lot of 'span' tags which are hidden and the isLastTask does not work because it counts the last of the non-visible and visible 'span' tags.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71vd.png

Here you can see how it does not remove the comma when the last visible span is not the overall last span.

P.S. Excuse me for the maybe confusing title, this is my first StackOverflow question!

Comment: Maybe with a filter for the ngfor? But how do I do it ?

Comment: can you show the code for isLastTaskEmployee

Comment: there is no code for isLastTaskEmployee, all there is I have shown it, it is only used in the ngFor, isLastTaskEmployee is the last element of the ngfor array. It works but I have empty spans which are not displayed because of the ngIF, but they still are counted to the last element, so the last element sometimes is an invisible element and thus it does not remove the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pipe to transform `apiEmployees`.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'employeelistPipe'})
export class EmployeeListPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(employees: IEmployee []): string {
        names: string[] = [];
        employees.forEach(employee => {
            names.push(`${employee.first_name} ${employee.last_name}`)
        });
        return names.join(", ")

    }
}
```

And afterward, you can use this pipe as

```
<span>{{apiEmployees | employeelistPipe}}</span>
```

**NOTE:** This code is not tested. It's just for an idea of how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thank you, using your example I researched multiple pipes and did finished it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pipe({ name: "employeelistPipe" })
export class EmployeeListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(employees: Employee[], employee_ids: number[]): string {
    var names: string[] = [];
    employees.forEach(employee => {
      if (employee_ids.includes(employee.id))
        names.push(`${employee.first_name} ${employee.last_name}`);
    });
    return names.join(", ");
  }
}
```

Created a pipe with additional arguments,where i pass the array of ids and after that i use it to filter it.

```
<span>{{apiEmployees | employeelistPipe:task.employees}}</span>
```

Here I have displayed the contents of the array.

Thank you @talha-junaid